# Inverse of product of 2 or more functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, products, inverse-function

I am interested to find the inverse of a product of 2 or more functions. For instance, suppose

$g(x) = \prod \limits_{i=1}^{n} [1 - x^{\alpha_i}], \quad x> 0, \alpha_i > 0$

Then, how do I find inverse of the function g? Is it the product of individual inverses?

Comment: "Inverse of a function can be found easily": what ???

Comment: Except in a few simple cases, there is no analytical solution to your question.

Comment: Do you mean inverse under addition, 123? or inverse under multiplication? or inverse under composition?

Comment: It's inverse under multiplication.

Comment: I posted an answer yesterday, 123. Was it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

There actually isn't a general formula for the inverse of $f\cdot g,$ where $f$ and $g$ are invertible functions. This is because the product of two invertible functions isn't necessarily invertible. For instance, on the nonzero real numbers, both $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ are invertible functions, but their product is $$f(x)\cdot g(x) = x\cdot \frac{1}{x} = 1,$$ which is neither injective nor surjective.

Comment: If we assume that the two functions are invertible, then what is the process of finding the inverse of their product.

Comment: There is no general process because the product of invertible functions is not necessarily invertible, which the counterexample I gave above demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that OP wants the inverse under *multiplication* (so, *not* under functional composition). So if $$g(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x)^{a_i}$$ then the inverse is given by $${1\over g(x)}={1\over\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x)^{a_i}}=\prod_{i=1}^n{1\over(1-x)^{a_i}}=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x)^{-a_i}$$

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. I don't think it will work like this. From what I see, it seems as the product of the individual inverses but I don't know if it's the correct procedure.

Comment: Of course it's the correct procedure. If you multiply $\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x)^{a_i}$ by $\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x)^{-a_i}$ then you get one, right? This wouldn't work if we were multiplying matrices, because matrix multiplication is not commutative, but multiplication of these functions is commutative, so the inverse of a product is the product of the inverses. How could it be wrong? Do you have an example where it goes wrong?

Comment: I don't know what more I can do to help you (especially when you don't respond).